# Goのシングルトンパターン

Tags: go, デザインパターン

http://qiita.com/kitoko552/items/82a4ae6952610bace169
上記サイトを参考にGolangでシングルトンパターンのプログラムを書きました。

```golang
package meta

type metaWords struct {
    PositiveWords []string
    NegativeWords []string
}

var sharedInstance = &metaWords{}

// GetInstance is singleton of meta words
func GetInstance() *metaWords {
    return sharedInstance
}
```

しかしこれだと、`GetInstance()`の箇所で`exported func GetInstance returns unexported type *meta.metaWords, which can be annoying to use`というGoLintの警告が出ます。

しかし`GetInstance()`を`metaWords`のメソッドにすると警告は消えますが、外部からインスタンスを取得できなくなります。
このエラーを消すにはどのようにすればいいのでしょうか。Goでシングルトンパターンはどのように実装すればいいのでしょうか。

Comment: `metaWords` を `MetaWords` にしてみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: 確かにこれで消えました。ありがとうございます。
でもこれだと外部からインスタンス化可能ですよね。仕方ないのでしょうか。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

構造体を公開するか、公開したくない場合は以下のようにしてください。

1. `metaWords` が公開するインターフェースを定義し、実装する
2. `GetInstance()` は構造体ではなくインターフェースを返す

これを手っ取り早く行うと、以下のようになります。

```golang
package meta

type MetaWords interface {
    PositiveWords() []string
    NegativeWords() []string
}

type metaWords struct {
    positiveWords []string
    negativeWords []string
}

func (m *metaWords) PositiveWords() []string {
    return m.positiveWords
}

func (m *metaWords) NegativeWords() []string {
    return m.negativeWords
}

var sharedInstance = &metaWords{}

// GetInstance is singleton of meta words
func GetInstance() MetaWords {
    return sharedInstance
}
```